# Turning find_all() results into text so it can be usable in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape content that is inside a `div` class inside another `div` class which repeats so I needed to use a `find_all` to get them. I want to be able to get them in text so when I put them in a dataframe it says the name of the object inside as you would get when you do a `find(...).text` instead of the entire html line

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.grammy.com/grammys/awards/winners-nominees/138'
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
category = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "view-grouping-content")
print(len(category))
for c in category:
    artistName = c.find_all('div', class_ = "views-field views-field-field-description")
```

Comment: please give the desired output of the first one-three rows of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = [x.text for x in soup.select(
        '.freelink.freelink-nid.freelink-internal')]
    print(goal)


main('https://www.grammy.com/grammys/awards/winners-nominees/138')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another angle of attack (if this could be from another site)...

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammy_Award_for_Record_of_the_Year'

page = requests.get(url)
tables = pd.read_html(page.text)
df = pd.concat(tables[1:9])
df.dropna(thresh=3, inplace=True)
df = df.rename(columns={'Year[I]':'Year'})
df['Year'] = df['Year'].str.replace('\[\d+\]', '', regex=True)
df['Record'] = df['Record'].str.replace('"', '', regex=False)
print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

[image]